# Is it possible to create a facebook event on the behalf of an application with Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to create a facebook event on the behalf of an application?
The idea is that the creator would be the facebook app and not a user, page, group...

According to the documentation this was possible in the old REST API but the graph api documentation doesn't seems to mention it.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. See this document describing how to use the graph API for Facebook Events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: i do belive its not supported in the graph api...as they say in their documentation:

Creating Events
To create an event on behalf of a User: instructions...
To create an event on behalf of a Page: instructions...

but not on behalf of a application